# Can one remove .class files from open file list in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an Android project in IntelliJ IDEA. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a file, the drop-down of file names includes both .class and .java files. The .class files are in the bin directory of my project.

I can see wanting .class files for external libraries (like a linked in jar file) but I don't want them for my own sources. I'm new to IDEA and assume this is a simple thing I just didn't do right, but I can't seem find it and it's driving me crazy. Any ideas?

Comment: Different solution discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247172/ignore-java-class-files-in-intellij-navigate-to-file-dialog

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set `bin` directory as **Excluded**, normally IDEA excludes all the output folders by default and doesn't show you any `.class` files.

[image: Exclude]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't set this up using IDEA--it was existing code--which explains why this wasn't done automatically.

Comment: it works for me but because my project is imported from sbt (actually the folder to exclude is not `bin` but `target`), it will probably be set back when I re-import it. Also, I think I cannot do that on the play sub-projects because play/sbt generate some source file in target...

Answer (score 19):

For Android Studio, there is a blue triangle when 'enter file name' (CMD + SHIFT + O) window is active. Clicking on the triangle brings down a drop down list of file types to be included/excluded in search

Comment: That really helped. Thanks.

Comment: in standard intellij, it is `ctrl+shift+N` but unchecking CLASS didn't work :-(

Answer (score 1):

When you hit Ctrl+Shift+N to open a file, you'll find the below drop down with the list of files and deselect class files under filter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmhxD.png

Comment: didn't work for me :-( but maybe I should update my intellij which is from 01/2018