# How to inactivate class in Tools window of project of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

What I want to do is to inactivate the one of java class in the tools window of project which is left sided of screen as usual. I tried to find how to inactivate it. But I could not find it. I guess it was existed in Eclipse on Windows version.

**My environment:**
Android Studio 0.4.0 on OSX

Do you know someone about it? Or, Could you tell me alternative way to inactivate?

Sincerely,

Comment: I found the way but still manually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use File> Settings > Compiler >Excludes to exclude some classes or file while compilation.

I never tried Inactive in Eclipse so not sure if this do the same which Eclipse Do.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. As a result, It did not work for me. I've wanted to inactivate(disable to load) the one of class because It's under debugging. I've requested Google about it.

Comment: There is information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762884/can-one-remove-class-files-from-open-file-list-in-intellij-idea