# Ignore Java .class files in IntelliJ navigate to file dialog?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntellJ, I can type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or select Navigate > File... to open the navigate to file dialog.

In my project, some dependencies bring in `.class` files, and when I search for their `.java` counterparts, the dialog gets polluted with the `.class` file results as well.

How can I make this dialog ignore all `.class` files?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the filter

[image]

deselect "Class" and they should not appear anymore.

Comment: Why was I expecting that list to be ordered alphabetically?! *facepalm*

Comment: Most of IntelliJ IDEA select list have a built-in search, just select the list and start type and it will start to search in the list