# Intellij 2016 - .class files not hidden in project mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I have a project where .class files are compiled and stored next to their .java version, as opposed to be kept in a separate output directory. In Intellij 14 and 15 the class files are automatically excluded from view, which is really helpful. It is not however the case for Intellij 2016.

How can I instruct the editor to hide class files placed in source directories - in Project view (not custom scope)?

Comment: Did you try that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762884/can-one-remove-class-files-from-open-file-list-in-intellij-idea

Comment: @alpert - this is not helpful in this scenario - I cannot exclude output directory, as it is the same as source directory

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-types.html

i.e. specify a filter for .class and make sure the setting to hide exclisions is set:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-tool-window.html

Comment: This unfortunately does not help - excluding .class files from project means code assist is not working anymore for any linked libraries, including jdk